# Why does Image Capture crash when downloading pictures from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

image capture crashes when I try to download photos from my iPhone to my MAC. It works OK with my wifes iPhone, but not mine anymore. I don't know why as I have been able to download from my iPhone previously.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a malformed/corrupt image on your phone.  Have you tried with alternative software like iPhoto?  It may simply be a case of identifying the culprit and removing it.